# what does training instance mean?

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation

I am new to machine learning. I just stumble across the term 'training instances' in a paper about using CNN for image segmentation. In that paper, a total 1100 images were used for modeling. The authors chose sub-regions from the images for training, and they presented a classification performance curve over 500K training instances. I am confused about they get such a large number of training instances from only 1100 images. Does one training instance mean one training sample or something else related to the training size?

Comment: Well, I think if you're choosing multiple sub-regions from 1100 images, you can get 500K training instances. Say, for example, you break an image into 10 small images and for each try to classify it it contains road, say. Will it be possible for you to share the link to the paper?

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize training instances as training batches. If there are millions of data-sets to test, you don't want to do them all at the same time but in instances or batches.

If you take 'n' images and split each image in 'm' sub-sections, you will get `n x m` subsections.

So in your case suppose we split each image in 4096 sections (why 4096, because its a even 64x64 grid split) we will get 
1100 * 4096 = 4505600 subsections of given training data.

To get 500K instances or subsets of training data , we simply divide  4505600  by  500k to get  9 images.
Thus we will get about 9 images in each of 500k subsets.

If the images are sufficiently dense in terms of pixel resolution and hence large in size, it may be possible to increase the subsections further to get greater number of images in each training batches or instances.

Answer (score 0):

An instance in a training dataset is a single observation of record data.